# jQuery validator addMethod always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am fairly new to jQuery validation http://validation.bassistance.de/ and am trying to create a custom event using addMethod. I have coded what appears to look correct but obviously isn't because if the event is true, then #email should be hidden with no message.

What is happening is that if the event is true or false, the message 'Please enter a value for testing!' is always fired. I have obviously made an error of epic proportions but cannot seem to find a way to correct it. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. I have only posted the relevant piece of code. Thanks

Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/DQjTc/

**UPDATE:** Just an update. I have noticed that if the submit button is pushed after validation, the correct message is entered and the false message does not. Which is what I need. Where do we go from here.

addMethod code

```
    $(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod( 'emailHide', function(value, element) 
    {

        if (element.value === '')

            {

                return false;
            }


                //return true;
                $('#email').hide();
                $('#emaillbl').html('Email address approved');


        },'Please enter a value for testing!'


    );
});
```

validation rules code

```
    $(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults(
    {
        errorClass: 'form_error_frmreport',
        errorElement: 'div'
    });

    $("#frmreport").validate(
    {
        rules:
        {

            email:
            {
                //required: true,
                email: true,
                emailHide: true
            },
            position:
            {
                required: true
            },
            feedback:
            {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages:
        {


            email:
            {
                //required: "<br />* required: You must enter a valid email address"
            },
            position:
            {
                required: "<br />* required: Please state your position"
            },
            feedback:
            {
                required: "<br />* required: Please enter as much information regarding the exact nature of the problem"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function()   {
                if ($("#frmreport").valid() === true)  { 
                var data = $("#frmreport").serialize();
                $.post('/sample/admin/frm10010.php', data, function(msg) {

               var messageOutput = '';
                for (var i = 0; i<msg.length; i++){
                    messageOutput += msg[i].box+'  ';     
                }
                $("#confirm_department").hide();


               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your report was successfully submitted and a representative will respond to you shortly.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Report submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
                $("#frmreport").get(0).reset();
                }, 'json');

         } else

         { 
           return; 
         }
        },
        success:  function()   {

                //validator.resetForm();
                //$.html("You have entered a box");
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }   

    });
});
```

Comment: try replacing === with a ==

Comment: @iBlue still the same error. thanks

Comment: can u post ur full code including html or a jsfiddle

Comment: iBlue http://jsfiddle.net/DQjTc/ ignore the submit and php values. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but try this
replace **`if (element.value ==='')` ** with **`if (value ==='')`**

Comment: Can you try this... Need to add **`return true`** in `ELSE` condition
 `if (element.value ===''){ return false;  } else { $('#email').hide(); return true;}`

Answer (score 1):

The value may contain white-space, so you should try:

```
if (element.value.trim() == '')
```

Not all browsers support [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), so you should place this at the top of your Javascript file.

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Comment: Mr.Polywhirl still the same result. Thanks